# Slowdown identified: ReaderWriterLock(-1). May I use different locks?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, locking

after hours of tracking mysterious one or two seconds long lasting "freeze" I finally found out that its ReaderWriterLock(-1). It is server app and the lock here is held for writing to client collection. Im not familiar with locking so I would like to ask if there is not any better/faster way? How about using lock object to lock add/read statements of collection?
This freeze occurs very randomly but its very annoying since it causes lag to all connected clients.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `AcquireReaderLock(-1)`/`AcquireWriterLock(-1)` or similar? That would suggest that the lock is contended - in which case, fix whichever code is holding the (write) lock at the time. If the delay is *literally* with the locking class, then *maybe* `ReaderWriterLockSlim` would have less overhead. `lock` would indeed be simpler still (hence cheaper), but doesn't allow the same granularity - it is essentially a mutex lock, so only one thread can play with the object. Contrast a reader/writer lock which allows one writer NAND multiple readers.

To be honest, it sounds as simple as "occasionally, some code will take a write lock (blocking other callers), and take a while to complete". *Finding* the offending code is a black art, but has little to do with the lock itself.